# @Html.DropdownList - unclear how to add Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using the helper to create a dropdown which works really well.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Free", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.Free, "Select Value", "Key")
```

normally I would just add a new argument with , new { @class = "xyz" }

This is not working with this usage as it doesn't take that many arguements, so unsure how to get the desired result?

Comment: What's that "Key" parameter? The class should be set in the fourth parameter.

Comment: In the C# controller, ViewBag.Free = new SelectList(await _metaDataService.GetMetaDataByTable("Free"), "Key", "Value");  It returns a Key and Value, I had assumed it referenced this?

Comment: This is the method's signature: IHtmlContent IHtmlHelper.DropDownList(string expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, string optionLabel, object htmlAttributes). The fourth parameter should be the attributes, and you should be able to set the class there. You already have the key in the SelectListItem instance itself.

Comment: So drop "Key" and add new { @Class = "xdd"} as normal?

Comment: Yes, that should work.